# How to extract the branch structure and the foliage from a tree image

Tags: image-processing, graphics, computer-vision

I am working on a problem where I need to extract the visible branching structure and the foliage from the tree separately. The suggested technique could be fully automatic or semi supervised(where the user draws a few strokes to help in segmentation). I would like to know how this can be implemented which tools or techniques or language would be the most convenient for accomplishing this task.

Comment: Do you have any assumptions about the image?  I.e. Can you be sure the background isn't more trees? Perhaps the background is mostly sky? Is the foliage mostly green?

Comment: Yes I can consider these assumptions.. what's the solution if the assumptions you listed are true. Also what if I say that the background doesn't have more trees but instead of just the sky there are buildings/walls/vehicles in the background.

Comment: Well, if the foliage is green, try looking at just the G channel. It might stand out more in comparison to the background. Or it might have a unique H value in HSV color space relative to the rest of the image, and if you can accept minimal user input, you could have them select one leaf, and then have a pretty narrow range of hues for finding other leaves, and it would be a little less sensitive to shadows. I'm going to write an answer so I can elaborate a little more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer necessarily, but this is too much to fit in a comment. I messed around with a picture of a tree for a few minutes.

Here's my original image:

[image]

I tried getting the difference between G and RB to highlight the greener areas using this (in MATLAB):

```
green_diff = 2*image(:,:,2) - (image(:,:,1)+image(:,:,3));
figure, imshow(green_diff)
```

[image]

I also tried looking at just the H channel in HSV color space.

```
htest = rgb2hsv(image);
htest(:,:,2:3) = 1;
figure, imshow(hsv2rgb(test))
```

You don't need to convert it back to rgb—it's just cooler to look at this way.

[image]

I don't have any good ideas for the branches right now. The only thing that really comes to mind is trying to take advantage of the fact that branches are connected to leaves, and that branches usually exhibit a tree-like shape (surprising, I know).

Comment: Thanks a lot Matthew Pope ... color segmentations seems to be a nice approach.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a possibility to remove the IR (Infra Red) filter on your camera? It can be done quite cheaply nowadays. If so, you could probably use the fact that the chlorophyl in the foliage reflects IR wavelengths quite strongly and therefore shows up bright in the IR wavelengths.

Try Googling *"NDVI"* (Normalised Difference Vegetation Index) for further explanation.

[Demonstration/Explanation of NDVI](http://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/Features/MeasuringVegetation/measuring_vegetation_2.php)

Comment: the image will be captured using a mobile phone so i don't think ndvi could be helpful. I need an approach which can segment out the tree from background first and then segment out the foliage and the visible branch from it.